# Rate of Convergence in CLT for IID random vectors with dependent entries

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Okay, so suppose I've got a sequence of IID random vectors $X_{n}$, where the entries of each $X_{n}=(X_{n,1},\dots, X_{n,i})$ are dependent. The motivating example here is the multinomial distribution: at each step we drop a ball into urn $i$ with probability $p_{i}$, $i=1\dots m$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ is a multinomial sample of size $n$.

Now, the CLT implies that $\sqrt{n}\big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}{n} - (p_{1},\dots,p_{m})\big)$ will converge to $N(0,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix associated with the multinomial. I'd like to know how fast this convergence in distribution is going to happen.

As far as I can tell, while there are Berry-Esseen type theorems for the multivariate CLT, they all requirethe covariance-matrix $\sigma$ to be the identity matrix. (Here's what I think is the classic work, by Gotze.)

http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176990448

But I can't assume that the entries of any $X_{n}$ are independent, since I'm dealing with a multinomial. Any ideas?

If worst came to worst, I could just use Berry-Esseen to bound every component individually. But that seems, well, crude and inelegant, and I'd like to avoid this solution if there's a better one available.

Comment: You might want to use the fact that $L\Sigma L'=I$ for some $L$ hence one knows the rate of convergence for $Y=LX$.

Comment: Very, very nice, Did. Gotze speaks as though we could take $\Sigma = I$ wlog, but I didn't see how that was supposed to work. But I understand now. And then we recover the rate of convergence (or a good bound thereon) for the original system. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's way too much to ask, but could you please clarify the similar issue in [my post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245224/multivariate-berry-esseen-please-help)? Your help will be immeasurable @Did