# Multivariate Berry-Esseen/ Please help!

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I've got a problem with understanding Berry-Esseen inequality for random vectors. You see, I keep coming across various forms of this theorem, all assuming a unit covariance matrix $I$, though it's seldom the case. I thought that maybe we can multiply the initial centered vector $X$ (or sum of vectors, if you please), for which we have the following:
$$
\sqrt{n} \left( X - \mu \right) \to N(0, \Sigma),
$$
– we can multiply our $X$ by some matrix $L : L \Sigma L^{\top} = I$, and then the new vector $LX$ will converge to $N(0, I)$ with the very same speed (and by speed I mean the same upper bound in Berry-Esseen).

Is it true? If not, why? And could you cast some light on what happens when the initial distribution is discrete - because in continuos case I can at the very least suggest that the abovementioned multiplication can be interpreted as a linear transformation, and therefore there will be change of density transformation with the determinant of Jacobian, and so on.

Please, help, this question drives me bonkers.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply you random vector with $\Sigma^{-1/2}$, where $\Sigma=E[XX^T]$ is the covariance matrix.

Let $\tilde X = \Sigma^{-1/2} X$, Then $$E[\tilde X\tilde X^T] = \Sigma^{-1/2} E[XX^T]\Sigma^{-1/2} = \Sigma^{-1/2}\Sigma\Sigma^{-1/2} = I.$$