# Gaussian approximation for general Covariance matrices

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

There are quite a few results in the literature that provide Berry-Esseen type bounds for the convergence of a standardized sum $S_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ of iid random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $X_1, \dots, X_n$ with $\mathbb{E}=0$ and $Cov(X_i)= I$, towards a standard normal vector $Y=\mathcal{N}(0, I)$. 
For example, [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqs_n8wIvLAhWK6RQKHR-fAQAQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mii.lt%2Ffiles%2FBentkus_2003_2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHZ9cEt2M3EyFv4Mv3oafPlMR8LqA) by Bentkus, where it is proven that, for the class of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ denoted by $\mathcal{C}$ it holds
$$
\sup_{C \in \mathcal{C}}| P(S_n \in C) - P(Y \in C)| \leq 400 d^{1/2}\beta/ \sqrt{n}.
$$
There exist other results of that kind, for example by [Goetze](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176990448) or Bhattacharya and Rao.
The authors also speak like a generalization to random vectors $X'$ with general Covariance $Cov(X')=\Sigma$ is rather straightforward. However, I do not see how this is done. 
The commenter, Did, in this related post [Rate of Convergence in CLT for IID random vectors with dependent entries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994673/rate-of-convergence-in-clt-for-iid-random-vectors-with-dependent-entries) has seemingly provided an answer.
He says: "You might want to use the fact that $L\Sigma L^T=I$ for some $L$". As far as I understand this means I could generalize the result in the following way:

Define $S'_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^nX'_i$, and $Y'= \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$. Above result then can be rewritten as 
$$
\sup_{C \in \mathcal{C}}| P(LS'_n \in C) - P(LY' \in C)| \leq 400 d^{1/2}\beta/ \sqrt{n}.
$$
and hence 
$$
\sup_{C \in \mathcal{C}}| P(S'_n \in L^{-1}C) - P(Y' \in L^{-1}C)| \leq 400 d^{1/2}\beta/ \sqrt{n}.
$$
and since $L^{-1}C$ is still a convex set, 
$$
\sup_{C \in \mathcal{C}}| P(S'_n \in C) - P(Y' \in C)| \leq 400 d^{1/2}\beta/ \sqrt{n}.
$$

Is this correct? It seems weird to me that the bound does not change actually.

Comment: No urge to communicate to the OP whose assertions you are discussing, that you are discussing them? This is a deliberate choice, I guess.